# Scrapy Recursive download of Content

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

After banging my head several time, I am finally coming here.

Problem : I am trying to download the content of each of the craiglist posting. **By content I mean the "posting body" like description of the cell phone.** Looking for a new old phone since iPhone is done with all excitement.

The code is an awesome work by **Michael Herman**.

My Spider Class

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import *
from craig.items import CraiglistSampleItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "craigs"
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://minneapolis.craigslist.org/moa/"]

    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("index\d00\.html", ),restrict_xpaths=('//p[@class="nextpage"]',))
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )

    def parse_items(self,response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//span[@class='pl']")
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = CraiglistSampleItem()
            item ["title"] = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
            item ["link"] = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

And the Item class

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class CraiglistSampleItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    link = Field()
```

Since the code will traverse many links , hence I wanted to save the description of each cell phone in sepearte csv but one more column in csv will be fine also.

Any lead !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of returning items in `parse_items` method you should return/yield scrapy [Request](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects) instance in order to get the description from the item page, `link` and `title` you can pass inside of an `Item`, and `Item` inside of the [meta](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta) dictionary:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import *

from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class CraiglistSampleItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    link = Field()
    description = Field()


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "craigs"
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://minneapolis.craigslist.org/moa/"]

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("index\d00\.html", ), restrict_xpaths=('//p[@class="nextpage"]',))
        , callback="parse_items", follow=True),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        titles = hxs.select("//span[@class='pl']")
        for title in titles:
            item = CraiglistSampleItem()
            item["title"] = title.select("a/text()").extract()[0]
            item["link"] = title.select("a/@href").extract()[0]

            url = "http://minneapolis.craigslist.org%s" % item["link"]
            yield Request(url=url, meta={'item': item}, callback=self.parse_item_page)

    def parse_item_page(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        item = response.meta['item']
        item['description'] = hxs.select('//section[@id="postingbody"]/text()').extract()
        return item
```

Run it and see additional `description` column in your output csv file.

Hope that helps.

Comment: many thanks for the code I almost lost all the confidence on scrapy and went for the route of lxml and bs4.. For the new users... The item.py file is separate and the "cralwer" file is separate. Also you may want to add "from craig_help.items import CraiglistSampleItem" to the cralwer where craig_help is the folder where the whole project is created.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. But it seems that "description" column is all blank. did I did something wrong by creating different file for item and crawler.

Comment: You are welcome. Sure, you can put your Item class in the appropriate place, just make sure that there are 3 fields there: `title`, `link` and `description`.

Comment: Unfortunately the description item is coming blank even after making changes... any lead about might be wrong in my code..

Comment: I'm very sorry - xpath expression was wrong - I've fixed it - please check.