# Recursive Scraping on Craigslist with Scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been trying to hone my python skills by building scrapers and recently switched from bs4 to scrapy so that I can use its multithreading and download delay features. I have been able to make a basic scraper and output the data to csv, but when I try to add a recursive feature I run into problems. I tried following the advice from [Scrapy Recursive download of Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509636/scrapy-recursive-download-of-content) but keep getting the following error:

DEBUG: Retrying http://medford.craigslist.org%20%5Bu'/cto/4359874426.html'%5D> DNS lookup failed: address not found

This makes me think the way I am trying to join the links isn't work as it's inserting characters into the url, but I can't figure out how to fix it. Any advice?

Here's the code:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        module1
# Purpose:
#
# Author:      CD
#
# Created:     02/03/2014
# Copyright:   (c) CD 2014
# Licence:     <your licence>
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import *

class PageSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "cto"

    start_urls = ["http://medford.craigslist.org/cto/"]

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("index\d00\.html", ), restrict_xpaths=('//p[@class="nextpage"]' ,))
        , callback="parse", follow=True), )

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//span[@class='pl']")
        for titles in titles:
            item = CraigslistSampleItem()
            item['title'] = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
            item['link'] = titles.select("a/@href").extract()

            url = "http://medford.craiglist.org %s" % item['link']
            yield Request(url=url, meta={'item': item}, callback=self.parse_item_page)

    def parse_item_page(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        item = response.meta['item']
        item['description'] = hxs.select('//section[@id="postingbody"]/text()').extract()
        return item
```

Comment: `url = "http://medford.craiglist.org %s" % item['link']` can't possibly be right, but I don't know what you actually wanted.  You might like to know about the standard-library [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) module.

Comment: I pulled that line from the link I posted. What I was trying to do is have it pull the link it found and add that to the Craigslist url to get the address for each page.

Comment: Insert `import sys` at the top of the file and `sys.stderr.write(repr(item[link]) + "\n")` immediately before the `url =` line.  What does it print?

Comment: Also, probably not your immediate problem, but `for titles in titles:` looks like a typo to me.  Shouldn't it be `for title in titles` or similar?

Comment: I thought the titles in titles was wrong too, but was following this tutorial - http://mherman.org/blog/2012/11/05/scraping-web-pages-with-scrapy/

I tried the code and got a list of links returned and then it started throwing that error. Tried the suggestion below as that was the format I had in my head, just couldn't remember the proper way to do it and it worked. I went through the codecademy and learnpythonthehardway courses, and am running into questions that the documentation would probably understand but it's still a little over my head. Any suggestions for learning the nuances more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out your code:

```
 url = "http://medford.craiglist.org %s" % item['link']
```

generates:

```
http://medford.craigslist.org [u'/cto/4359874426.html']
```

The `item['link']` returns a list in your code and not a string as you are expecting it to. You need to do this:

```
url = 'http://medford.craiglist.org{}'.format(''.join(item['link']))
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you for explaining WHY I was having the error and not just how to fix it. That makes sense and the .join was what I thought I needed I just couldn't make it work before attempting what I originally posted. If only I could give extra points...

One more question if you're able to help, since Craigslist has pages of 100 listings, how would I implement a recursive scrape of the links on the first page and then do the same for the following pages? For example, first page is medford.craigslist.org/cto/ and then second page is http://medford.craigslist.org/cto/index100.html,  etc